# how to implement sass in sencha touch 2.0

Tags: sencha-touch-2, sass, sencha-touch-theming

Please tell me how to include our own pictos in sencha 2.0.  This is my `.scss` file.

```
$base_color:#FF83D6;

@import 'sencha-touch/default/all';

@include sencha-toolbar-ui('india', #66FF66, 'matte');
@include sencha-button-ui('india', #66ff66, 'matte');
@include sencha-button-ui('india', #66ff66, 'matte');

@include pictos-iconmask(PICTOS_NAME);
```

`PICTOS_NAME` should be replaced with what so that I can use it?

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.0.2/#!/api/Global_CSS-css_mixin-pictos-iconmask

> `pictos-iconmask( $name )`
>
> Includes a base64-encoded icon for use within tab bars and buttons
>   (With the component parameter iconMask: true).
>
> `@include pictos-iconmask('attachment');`
>
> $name : string
>
> The name of the icon to be included. This is to match the name of the
>   icon file (located at `resources/themes/images/default/pictos`)
>   without its extention (.png).